# What is a good way to parse JSON response with varied data types?

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to write API calls to retrieve the last package status using UPS Tracking API. However, it seems that the JSON strings returned by the API vary in the data type returned - for example, `["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"]` returns either a JSON string or a list of JSON strings.

I am currently managing these using the below try / except statements. If a list of JSONs is returned instead of a singular JSON string, I specify that I am looking for the first JSON string in the list.

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    response_json=response.json()
    try:
        status = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"]["Activity"][0]["Status"]["Type"]
        code = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"]["Activity"][0]["Status"]["Code"]
        location = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"]["Activity"][0]["ActivityLocation"]["Address"]["City"]
    except:
        status = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"][0]["Activity"][0]["Status"]["Type"]
        code = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"][0]["Activity"][0]["Status"]["Code"]
        location = response_json["TrackResponse"]["Shipment"]["Package"][0]["Activity"][0]["ActivityLocation"]["Address"]["City"]
```

Unfortunately, this seems like it isn't going to work well as there are multiple parts of the API response where this issue is occurring. Eg."Activity" also returns a JSON if only one activity was found, or a list of JSONs if multiple activities are returned.

Is there a more elegant way of resolving these issues, besides writing multiple nested if/else or try/except statements to test the datatype returned at each point of the JSON response?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try json.normalize?

Comment: @Anti_cse51 Nope i haven't - newbie here trying to see what everyone else is doing. thanks for the suggestion!